# How to create a DEB file manually?

Tags: debian

I want to create a DEB file manually. I would like to just provide a folder which contains data to install, and a script to be executed after installation.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've used the knowledge embedded in the answers below to implement a deb generator for the Guix tool; perhaps its source can be a useful reference; see: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guix.git/tree/guix/scripts/pack.scm#n659.  It's usable via the CLI like: `guix pack --format=deb hello`, where `hello` is the name of a Guix package to archive as a deb.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### Making a source package

My recommendation is to make a source package. Install [build-essential](http://packages.debian.org/build-essential), [debhelper](http://packages.debian.org/debhelper), [dh-make](http://packages.debian.org/dh-make). Change to the directory where the files you want to install are (the directory name must be of the form `$PACKAGE-$VERSION`, e.g. `myapp-4.2-1` for your first attempt at packaging Myapp V4.2), and run `dh_make --createorig`. Answer the questions. Debhelper will create the basic infrastructure needed to build a package by generating files in a subdirectory called `debian`, both some mandatory files and templates for optional files. You may need to modify some of these files:

- Edit [`debian/rules`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#rules) to build what needs building and install the files in the right place. If you just need to copy some files and not to compile stuff, just edit the file [`debian/install`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#install) to specify which files need to be installed where.
- Edit [`debian/copyright`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#copyright) to add license information about your package and information on where to get the latest version (if relevant).
- Edit [`debian/changelog`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#changelog) to remove the reference to an ITP (that's only relevant if you're working for the Debian project). Rename `debian/postinst.ex` to [`debian/postinst`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#maintscripts) and add your post-installation commands there. If you later update your package, run `debchange -i` to add a changelog entry or edit the file in Emacs (with [dpkg-dev-el](http://packages.debian.org/dpkg-dev-el) installed).

Run `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc` to build the `.deb` package (remove `-us -uc` if you want to sign the package with your PGP key).

### Making a binary package directly

If you decide to make a binary package directly without building it from a source package, which is not really easier because there aren't as many tools to facilitate the process, you'll need some basic familiarity with the format of deb packages. It is described in the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/), in particular [ch. 3 (format of binary packages)](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html), [ch. 5 (control files)](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html), [ch. 6 (installation scripts)](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) and [appendix B (binary package manipulation)](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-binarypkg.html).

You make sure that your package installs the expected files `/usr/share/doc/copyright` (containing the license of the package contents, as well as where to find the latest version of the package) and `/usr/share/doc/changelog.Debian.gz` (containing the changelog of the deb package). You don't need these if you're only going to use the package in-house, but it's better to have them.

#### On Debian and derivatives

If you have the Debian tools available, use `dpkg-deb` to construct the package. In the directory containing the data to install, add a directory called `DEBIAN` at the top level, containing the control files and maintainer scripts.

```
$ ls mypackage-42
DEBIAN etc usr var
$ dpkg-deb -b mypackage-42
```

#### The hard way

If you don't have the Debian tools, build an archive of the files you want to package called `data.tar.gz`, a separate archive of the control files called `control.tar.gz` (no subdirectories), and a text file called `debian-binary` and containing the text `2.0`.

```
cd mypackage-42
tar czf ../data.tar.gz [a-z]*
cd DEBIAN
tar czf ../../control.tar.gz *
cd ../..
echo 2.0 > debian-binary
ar r mypackage-42.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
```

You need at least a [control file](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-binarycontrolfiles) with the fields `Package`, `Maintainer`, `Priority`, `Architecture`, `Installed-Size`, `Version`, and any necessary dependency declaration.

The script to be executed after installation is called `postinst`. Be sure to make it executable. It goes alongside `control`.

#### Converting a binary package from a different format

If you already have a binary package from another distribution, you can use [alien](http://packages.debian.org/alien) to convert it.

Comment: The answer presupposes the OP knows how to use emacs. Is emacs really necessary here? For editing changelogs, I think one can use `dch -i`.

Comment: What is `ar` doing that `tar` is not?

Comment: @mmstick It's a different format. I don't know why the designers of the deb format chose to use ar here.

Comment: `changelog.Debian.gz` may as much be `changelog.gz`. It just must be compressed with `gzip --best` or else Lintian will complain.

Comment: About `ar r mypackage-42.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz` it could be worth to stress the order is important: control must come before data.

Comment: If you want to change the name and email that `dh_make --createorig` uses, you need to `export DEBEMAIL="me@example.com"` and `export DEBFULLNAME="Firstname Lastname"` beforehand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing how to do this manually.  The format as documented at https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/dpkg-dev/deb.5.en.html mentions that the ar archive should have a "magic value of !<arch>"; would you know how this can be added?

Comment: @user30747 You don't need to add anything. That's just part of the ar format produced by `ar` from GNU binutils, which is what you'd normally have on Linux. I think this format is the same as BSD `ar`. If you're using a different OS it might have a different format, but GNU binutils are usually easy to install everywhere. And the tar format likewise has to be a format understood by GNU tar, but I think it can read all the classic tar formats.

Comment: +1 For the very important commentary: the control file should have **no subdirectories**. I was trying to create a `.deb` file with a control file with all files in the subdirectory `control`—What a waste of time!

Answer (score 11):

First off you need to create a build folder and an archive of your files: `tar czvf data.tar.gz files`

Then in the build folder you must create a control file with some wanted informations:

```
 Package: xxxxxx
 Version: 0.0.1
 Section: user/hidden 
 Priority: optional
 Architecture: armel
 Installed-Size: `du -ks usr|cut -f 1`
 Maintainer: Your Name <xxx@xxx.xx>
 Description: This is optional, but creates warnings if left out
```

Then you can add independently preinst, postint, prerm and postrm shell scripts to control pre and post install and pre and post remove behaviour of the .deb file and then you can create the control archive with tar: `tar czvf control.tar.gz control preinst postinst prerm postrm`

Then you need a debian-binary file: `echo 2.0 > debian-binary`. In your build folder you should have now these files: `debian-binary` `control.tar.gz` and `data.tar.gz`.

Finally you need `ar` package to create the .deb file: `ar -r xxx.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz`

Comment: About `ar -r xxx.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz` it could be worth to stress the order is important: control must come before data.

Comment: @Bytemain, the top voted answer looks indeed partially based on your text, but it adds details to it, and it's better readable.  the sequence we can copy/paste makes it particularly more handsome.

Answer (score 3):

I do a lot of packages, and to do a full one is not a trivial matter.  On a positive note, files and scripts are much less work.  You can create such a package, very simply, with a tool known as [debreate](https://sourceforge.net/projects/debreate/).

Debreate is a really simple GUI, for just creating simple DEB packages.  You can just specify which files, where they go, and if/what should execute on post/pre install/uninstall.  I used to just do all my packages the standard way, but after I started using this tool, I will only go back when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

[See the Debian Wiki on Packaging](http://wiki.debian.org/Packaging), maybe `equivs` (see link) already satisfies your requirements.

[Wikipedia's page on the `deb` file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) also includes many useful links.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this with Zimbra 7 on Debian using its Ubuntu packages. (I'm stubborn, I like Debian > bUbuntu despite Zimbra releasing only for Ubuntu.) Not sure how I worked around this before, I'm certain I didn't have to do this when I installed this previously!

```
mkdir new
for i in *.deb
 do echo `date`: working on $i
 ar x $i
 cd control
 rm * 2> /dev/null
 tar -xzpvf ../control.tar.gz
 tr "_" "-" < control > control2
 mv -v control2 control
 tar -czpvf ../control.tar.gz .
 cd ..
 ar r new/$i debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
done
rm -rf debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz control
```

All your new .deb files will be in `new/`.

**Note**: this was on squeeze - dpkg on wheezy has --force-bad-version now.

Answer (score 1):

For quick creating of packages you can user checkinstall program. It do a instalation of program, watch changes - and create a deb or rpm package of it.

Comment: This sounds like a great option for tracking packages you have to install from source. Can you offer more details? E.g., in the course of installation you can change symlinks, delete files, edit config files, add daemons, etc ... to what extent doees checkinstall track and undo these changes? Can you easily modify its output to add prerm and postrm scripts?

Comment: look at https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall
If you want to change things during install - easiest way is modify Makefile to change install section. prerm/postrm - i didn't find way to modify it. It's just for small programs to allow simple uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use official debian helpers, the `termux-create-package` python script can also be used to create binary deb files as per debian policies based on yaml/json manifest files and provides some utility config parameters as well.

https://github.com/termux/termux-create-package

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alien to convert to .deb format from Slackware tgz.  Slackware packages are insanely simple in that they don't really do anything much more than what the OP was asking for namely, copy some files, and run a script.  This would save creating the control file and so on because Alien will generate it.

```
mkdir pkg
pushd pkg
mkdir -p usr/local/bin install
touch usr/local/bin/xxx   # <--- something to install
touch install/slack-desc   # <---- optional description
cp <<script>> install/doinst.sh  # <---- your post-install
tar zcvf ../xxx-1-x86_64-1.tgz *
popd
alien --to-deb --scripts xxx-1-x86_64-1.tgz
```

If you are unfamiliar with the Slackware package format, note that your install directory in the tarball will **not** be installed to the target, and if you want a .deb that **does** update files under /install this is probably not going to work!

Answer (score -3):

```
$ apt-get install build-essential dh-make debhelper devscripts
$ wget http://nmap.org/dist/nmap-LAST.tar.bz2
$ tar xf nmap-LAST.tar.bz2
$ cd nmap-LAST
$ dh_make -s -e youremail@site.org -f ../nmap-LAST.tar.bz2
$ apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev flex bison libpcap0.8-dev \
  libpcre3-dev binutils-dev python-all-dev
$ dpkg-buildpackage
```