# Repackaging a Debian package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging

I need instructions on how to do repackage a `.deb` package.

Situation:

I have a `.deb` package for an application with no source.  I need to modify a `Description` field, save the file change and repackage back into a `.deb` package.

Is there a step by step on how to do that?

Comment: See also [How to create a DEB file manually?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30303)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the control file. This is the process:

```
dpkg-deb -x foo.deb tmpdir
dpkg-deb --control foo.deb tmpdir/DEBIAN
nano tmpdir/DEBIAN/control
dpkg -b tmpdir modified.deb
```