# Installing WiFi driver on machine with no internet

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, network-interface

I have an old laptop with only a WiFi card for internet access. I've installed lubuntu server since it would fit on a CD (no DVD). It didn't recognize my Linksys WPC54Gv3 adapter, so I downloaded the `bcm43xx-fwcutter_005-2_i386.deb` on another machine and copied it over on a thumb drive.

When I try to install the package (`dpkg -i ...`), it tries to download `wl_apsta.o`, which it of course can't. I've downloaded, this file, but can't figure out how to make the install it use the local file, rather than go to the network for it.

I've found some pages that make it look like you install `b43-fwcutter`, then use it to install the .0 file, but I can't seem to do it in two steps.

Comment: Would it be an option to purchase a supported USB-Ethernet dongle or Wifi-dongle to get internet access while you do this work?  Then when the driver is up and running you can remove the dongle again.

Comment: So, I did manage to find an old PCMCIA ethernet card and get online. When I try to install the package (bcm43xx-fwcutter), it fails because the installer is trying to download the required .o file from a non-existent web address (http://boredklink.googlepages.com/wl_apsta.o). I think this has now evolved into a bug in the Debian package. Not sure how to report this.

Comment: Got WiFi working by plugging in to Ethernet and running: sudo apt-get download firmware-b43-installer, then sudo dpkg -i firmware-b43-installer*.deb   This all has to be done connected to internet, because package downloads more stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATED

**All updated content is bold.**

I can provide you with a short outline for one possible solution (there are multiple ways of course as usual). As soon as I have more time I can give more detail for each step.

1. Download the deb package
2. extract the deb archive - `ar vx bcm43xx-fwcutter_005-2_i386.deb`
3. extract the `data.tar.gz` **and `control.tar.gz`**
4. in there modify the file `usr/share/bcmxx-fwcutter/install_bcm43_firmware.sh`
5. Delete line 10 saying `$DL http...`
6. **Save the file and do `md5sum usr/share/bcmxx-fwcutter/install_bcm43_firmware.sh`**
7. **Copy the generated checksum and paste it into the `control/md5sums` on line 2 (overwriting the prior checkum)**
8. **save the modified md5sums file**
9. put `wl_apsta.o` into the `/tmp` directory
10. package the `data.tar.gz` archive with the modified file
11. **package the control.tar.gz with the modified checksums file**
12. package the deb archive with the modified data **and control** archive ([How to create debian file manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/how-to-create-a-deb-file-manually))
13. Install the deb package

### EDIT EXPLANATION

Forgot about the step to recreate the md5sum of the edited file and put the value into the `control/md5sums`.

Comment: it looks like "ar" is not part of the lubuntu server install....

Comment: Got all this working, but bcm34xx-fwcutter is now complaining about unknown MD5sums when I run dpkg -i

Comment: sorry forgot about the md5sums. fixed that

Answer (score 2):

According to [linux-wireless](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/), you can install the `b43` driver as follows:

Download the `b43-fwcutter` from [here](https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/) e,g (`b43-fwcutter_019-3_i386.deb`):

```
wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_019-3_i386.deb
```

Then install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_019-3_i386.deb
```

Download the `broadcom-wl` packge:

```
wget http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
```

Install the driver:

```
export FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DIR="/lib/firmware"
sudo b43-fwcutter -w "$FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DIR" broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

Unload driver:

```
modprobe -r b43 bcma wl brcmsmac
```

Load the right one (e,g): `b43`:

```
modprobe b43
```

**Edit**:

It is possible to install packages on your **offline** machine through [Cube-server](https://launchpad.net/cube-server)  , it can be installed also on windows machine ( **Online** ) to download the needed package:

To install `cube-server` on your linux machine, you need to download `zip` file through the navigator or using `wget`:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/cube-server/trunk/0.1/+download/cube-server-installer-0.1.98_Linux64bit.zip
```

to install it run:

```
 unzip cube-server-installer-0.1.119_Linux64bit.zip
 ./cube-server-installer install
```

To launch it run: `cube-server`

Follow the 4 steps described [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/207826183/cube-server-tutorial.pdf):

1. Install and Run cube-server on Linux
2. Install and run Cube Server on Windows
3. Download repositories, upgrade outdated installed applications, and
   download new applications on Windows ( **in your case download the `broadcom-sta-dkms` or the `b43fwcutter`** , it depends on the model of your wifi-card )
4. Install applications on Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can also use USB tethering. Connect your mobile to your wifi (or you can use mobile data). Now you can access internet on your system and easily install drivers.